# Node js change values within page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, button, handlebars.js

I have a little problem on my nodejs application. I started to develop on this language by some time now and I have clear a lot of processes.

I am developing an application that can write and save the records on DB, I successfully configured Sequelize for this and the main structure process of the library are clear. I also have used Handlebars to render pages and compose the frontend also adding methods for the comparison of values and so on.

Now I have a lack of information about a thing that could be very basic and simple: I have a page on witch I have to write in text fields some values and control the user that can change this values with plus and minus buttons as in a ecommerce basket. At the end of the selections all the values have to be submitted, checked and saved on the DB if the check is right. I need to know how I can change values in the page with the plus and minus buttons without change page or submit anything until the user confirm that the selection is finished.

For now I just had to do submissions but now I have to change values as they will be volatile and when there is confirmation check everything. I found no clue in Nodejs or in Handlebars on how I can change value staying on the webpage without post action on every single click. The submission functions and pages rendering is clear I need to know how is to develop the part of the value changes without leaving the page. There will be ranges and others things but if you can provide me a documentation or an example on how I can speak to my page will be all clear.

Comment: **Unrelated:** Nodejs is not a language!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: The JavaScript code executed by nodejs is server side code, and server side code cannot access, modify or react on client side elements, like the plus/minus sign. You need to do this client side. There are many ways to solve that, using pure JavaScript, using libraries like jQuery, or using complex libraries like VueJS, Angular, React or EmberJS.

Comment: Hello and thank you, so what you suggest is to pass the parameters that I take from the server and then use a client side script. My doubt was how to initialize all the vars I need from the server and if node can handle the handlebars pages in some way. I will look in this direction and let you know if it works fine in my project.